# Android Studio doesn't start up, saying SDK components were not installed

Tags: android, android-studio

I have download Android Studio packed with the full SDK (build-tools, platforms, everything). Installed the studio (64-bit) on Drive C and the SDK in "AppData/local/Android/android-sdk" folder as specified by the installer itself.
Now when I run the Studio (with admin permissions) it still attempts to download everything, as if no SDK components were present on my PC.
Is there a way to tell the Studio where the SDK is? Or I have to re-download it all?? (I already have everything mentioned in the error message)

"The following SDK components were not installed: platform-tools, extra-android-m2repository, tools, addon-google_apis-google-21, build-tools-21.1.2, android-21, sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21, source-21,"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The following SDK component was not installed: platform-tools]

I ran into the same issue and was able to solve it by updating the SDK from the command line.
Go to the location where your Android SDK was installed (possibly ~/Android/Sdk) and run:

`./android update sdk --no-ui`

There's no need to run it as root.

Then, on Android Studio, go on Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure, and then point Android SDK Location to wherever it is located.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

step1: just copy 21.1.2 folder and paste with name 21.1.1
step2 : open 21.1.1 folder and open "source properties" file with any text editor( notepad)
step3 : change pkg.Revision=21.1.1   save it
step 4: android studio

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chown -R <username> .android
```

as mentioned [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76268), android sdk updater stores a copy of some xmls in `.android/cache`
So after you have set the permissions, the updater can store necessary xmls and download missing sdk components